# Returning copy of object

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't understand what the difference is between these two bits of code, as they behave the same way.

```
- (NSArray *)handleImages
{
     NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];
     //...Do something with the array..
     return [images copy];
}


- (NSArray *)handleImages
{
     NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];
     //...Do something with the array..
     return images;
}
```

Comment: well, the first one creates an (immutable) copy. what's the problem?

Comment: There is no problem, i'm just wondering what the difference is between returning an object, versus returning a copy of an object... So the difference is that it returns an immutable copy, and in the second example, it returns a mutable array?

Comment: The copy is a different object. You don't return the object itself, but another, new object, identical to the original one. It is unnecessary and not useful in this particular case.

Comment: the first returns an `NSArray` object the second one returns an `NSMutableArray` which only casted as `NSArray`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is set to return an immutable array. The first version converts the mutable array it creates into an immutable array before returning it. The second version simply returns the mutable array. The first version is a little *cleaner*, since the caller expects an immutable array.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly the answer i was looking for. Makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

The first method returns the immutable array where in you can't modify the returned object.

But second method returns the mutable array where in you can modify the returned object

Ex:
`

```
- (NSArray *)handleImages
{
     NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray new];
     //...Do something with the array..
     return images;
}

-(void)anyMethod
{
    NSMutableArray *array = (NSMutableArray *)[self handleImages];

    if([array respondsToSelector:@selector(addObject:)])
    {
        [array addObject:@"Any Object"]; // You can add any object to this array
    }
}
```

`

Comment: that is a poor explanation, (however the issue is exactly the same) because the caller class basically cannot afford such explicit casting, what you did here, without risking crash.

Comment: This is added just for his understanding purpose.